# Sublime Text is autocorrecting "^" in LaTeX

Tags: sublime-text, binding

I use Sublime Text 3 for my LaTeX coding. Whenever I try to type something with a carat such as `e^{x+2}` it autocorrects it to `e{{x+2}}`. The autocorrect occurs right after typing the first curly brace.

I've looked through my Key Binding settings but it all looks pretty foreign to me. This [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/140169/sublime-text-snippets-just-for-latex) here seems to refer to adding this autocorrection, but again is tough for me to understand what is going on.

Comment: This seems to be a Sublime Text issue rather than a LaTeX issue. I would suggest asking at https://apple.stackexchange.com

Comment: I put it here since it only happens in ST when I'm working with a .tex file, but I can try asking over there as well!